# Lower order component Routes not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm learning some React and have a question w.r.t. routing.

I'm using react-router 4. In my index file I have a Router with 3 Routes defined as such:

```
<Router>
    <div>
        {indexRoutes.map((p, k) => {
            return <Route exact path={p.path} component={p.component} key={k} />;
        })}
    </div>
</Router>
```

The pages are: home, login and a restricted members area. The members area isn't protected by authentication yet (shouldn't matter for the purpose of the question).

The member area has a menu with Link which change the main content according to what was clicked. The selection of the relevant component is done in a Switch. What happens is that the home and the login pages work fine but the members page just loads the template and when I click on the links I just get blank pages.

I can get the members pages to work fine if I don't have the higher order router (the one with home, login, members) and just have the members page referenced from index.

How can I make the lower level routes work as intended?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-router-dom, you can use a [Switch](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch). Wrap all your `<Routes />` into a switch component, instead using Router. Like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

<Switch>
  {indexRoutes.map((p, k) => {
      return <Route exact path={p.path} component={p.component} key={k} />;
  })}
</Switch>
```

And then embbed the Switch into your app, as you do with the Router.

Comment: How does that help with my problem?

Comment: ...do not mix Router and Switch?